# Tweek Google Chrome browser for all users

Tags: google-chrome, browser, default-settings

I'm preparing an install that will be used by hundred of LDAP users (classroom) and would like that when Google Chrome launches, it

1. doesn't ask to become the default browser
2. doesn't ask to send usage statistics ad crash reports

Is there a way to prevent such questions to be asked in a system wide manner?

Or is there a way to prepare a default (and minimal) `.config/google-chrome/` that can be saved in `/etc/skel`?

Or any thing else that could be automated during session opening?